# Pandas update row value in column B based on row value in column A

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, conditional-statements

Below is an example of my `data frame`. I have created column B where the value for each row is NaN

```
      Column A    Column B

1        Xo          NaN     
2       Es-Ab        NaN
3       Pr-Ab        NaN
4       Pr-Bs        NaN
5       Tr-Ab        NaN
6        Ab          NaN
7        Es          NaN
8       Es-Bs        NaN
```

I need to insert values in Column B based on the string value in Column A. Need to write a case-statement, i.e. if/elif/else function in python perhaps. Need help with the logic/syntax in python as before inserting values I also need to check if the row value in Column B is `NaN`.

The pseudo code block i'm envisioning is as follows:

```
if (column A contains X) and (column B = NaN) then ABC
if (column A contains Ab or Pr) and (column B = NaN) then DEF
if (column A contains Es) and (column B = Nan) then GHI
else Other
```

And I need to evaluate this for each row of my data frame and assign the row value in Column B as per the above logic. Thus, my final outcome would look like:

```
      Column A    Column B

1        Xo          ABC     
2       Es-Ab        DEF
3       Pr-Ab        DEF
4       Pr-Bs        DEF
5       Tr-Ab        DEF
6        Ab          DEF
7        Es          GHI
8       Es-Bs        GHI
```

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Have you actually tried anything? Also, plain "contains" checks are flimsy, be careful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using numpy :

```
import numpy as np
col_a = 'Column A'
col_b = 'Column B'


conditions = [
            (df[col_a].str.contains('X')) & (df[col_b].isnull()),
             (df[col_a].str.contains('Ab|Pr')) & (df[col_b].isnull()),
            (df[col_a].str.contains('Es')) & (df[col_b].isnull())
             ]

outputs = ['ABC','DEF','GHI']

df[col_b] = np.select(conditions,outputs,default='Other')
```

---

```
print(df)
  Column A Column B
0     1 Xo      ABC
1  2 Es-Ab      DEF
2  3 Pr-Ab      DEF
3  4 Pr-Bs      DEF
4  5 Tr-Ab      DEF
5    6  Ab      DEF
6    7  Es      GHI
7  8 Es-Bs      GHI
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with apply.

This should work:

```
def get_columnB(row):
    a = row["Column A"]
    b = row["Column B"]
    if b != np.NaN:
        return "Other"
    elif "X" in a:
        return "ABC"
    elif "Ab" in a or "Pr" in a:
        return "DEF"
    elif "Es" in a:
        return "GHI"
    return "Other"

df["Column B"] = df.apply(get_columnB,axis=1)
```

Be careful I don't know if it's important that it's case sensitive. So if it's not case sensitive use `lower()`

```
a = row["Column A"].lower()
b = row["Column B"].lower()
```

and change `"X"`, `"AB"`... to `"x"`, `"ab"`

Answer (score 1):

You can apply the conditions in 3 lines and fill the rest with other

```
df.loc[df['column A'].str.contains('X'), 'B'] = ABC
df.loc[df['column A'].str.contains('Ab|Pr'), 'B'] = DEF
df.loc[df['column A'].str.contains('Es'), 'B'] = GHI
df['B'] = df['B'].fillna('Other')
```